# facing a dual boot issue

Tags: ubuntu, dual-boot

I have a 500 GB hard disk and it haas been partitioned into 4 partitions namely C,D,E,F.

Windows 7 version is installed in C drive while Ubuntu 16.04 is installed in D drive. The other two partitions contain my personal data. I had first installed Windows 7 and then later did also install Ubuntu (in dual boot mode). When asked for the root point, I specified /. As a result my laptop is configured to run both the operating systems. A startup screen comes where I select the OS to work with and then I continue with the selected OS.

Currently I am facing some issues with Windows 7 OS and the situation demands a reinstall of the same. Is it possible to re-install Windows 7 without having to remove and re-install Ubuntu?

A similar situation came some months back and I just removed both the OS one by one. I do not want to go through the same energy draining procedure again.

Could you please help me with the procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Reinstall windows, wiping the ubuntu partition also, ie full installation. 
The error `grub rescue` will occur. To overcome that, launch the command prompt from the windows boot drive/cd and use the commands

> `bootrec /fixmbr` and `bootrec /fixboot`

The windows should boot normally, and now you can reinstall ubuntu